# Favicon for internal Salesforce users

Tags: lightning-experience, favicon

I changed the favicon for my Community.  I would like to have a favicon for my internal users who are accessing Salesforce Enterprise.  Is this possible?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I can't think of any way to do it but I've been wrong before.

Comment: Is [**this**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000167021&type=1) something you are looking for?

Comment: Jayant...the information you provided tells me how to put a favicon on a Community.  I am looking to change the favicon for my internal Salesforce users (if possible).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realized that it was for community.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it is a Chrome browswer extension that will override the default Salesforce icons:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-colored-favico/peohlnebahcddpmfaplmilpkgbkkcdho?hl=en

According to the description:

> Overrides the standard salesforce favicon with one colored based on the org. Also, displays a separate icon for sandbox instances.
>
> Automatically updates the icon for salesforce.com to display a colored cloud icon based on the current instance. Also, includes a separate icon with an 'S' to indicate sandbox instances.
>
> Now supports Lightning Experience!

Also, it may be possible to customize the solution that the author has provided.

**UPDATE:**  I am editing the answer in response to a comment.  ***I have no affiliation at all*** with the author of the Google chrome extension I cited.

I did confirm that changing the "favicon" in any html page requires a modification to the HTML  tag.  The Salesforce platform is never going to allow code that manipulates their generated HTML markup.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

A browser extension to customize the icon may be the only way to do this, and this browser extension is fairly highly rated.  A potential downside is that it requires access to read and modify data from websites that you visit.

Also, you may want to take a look at some of the comments on the Chrome extension's "Support" page.  If Doug Ayers has installed this extension and got it to work in SF Lightning experience by tweaking a javascript file, that's something to consider.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but it might improve your post to explicitly disclose your affiliation or lack thereof with this product.

Comment: I am very leary of Chrome extensions because of the many security issues with them.  I don't think I will use that solution.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Point of clarification: changing a favicon can be accomplished in two ways, either by setting a `<link rel="icon" . . . />` tag in the page header or by directing the request for `GET /favicon.ico` to a different image file (which itself can be accomplished either by placing a file in the web root directory or by a server URL rewrite rule). Of course, none of these methods are currently supported, but Salesforce could do so without giving raw HTML editing capabilities to end users.